# Reparametrization of multivariable fisher information

Tags: statistics, fisher-information

The task is to prove that reparametrization of multivariable Fisher information  with diffeomorphism $\eta: \Theta \rightarrow H$ is 
$$
I(\eta)=\bigg(\frac{\partial \theta^T}{\partial \eta}\bigg)I(\theta)  \bigg(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \eta^T}\bigg),
$$
for given $I(\theta)$.

My solution:

We know that multivariable Fisher information is 
$$
I(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\bigg\{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log{(f_\theta(x))}\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log{(f_\theta(x))}\bigg]^T\bigg\}.
$$

We can apply chain rule 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}= \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Rightarrow  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} = \bigg(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \eta}\bigg)^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}
%\theta'(\eta)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}
$$

Applying it to the first equation and changing $\theta \mapsto \eta$ we obtain
$$
I(\eta)=\mathbb{E}\bigg\{\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\eta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log{(f_\eta(x))}\bigg[\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\eta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log{(f_\eta(x))}\bigg]^T\bigg\}.
$$
Now it's somewhere close to solution, what I would like to do is to take this $\big(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial\eta}\big)$s out of the expected value and tell that it is done.
But I don't think it is correct.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the proof steps.  The first 3 lines are a Binomial reparametrization example. You can ignore them, and they will not impact the proof below. However, it will help you to understand the proof when you feel confuse. 
[image: (image with formulas)]